# In how many ways can $20$ men and $80$ women be seated at $10$ round tables so that there are $8$ women and $2$ men at each table?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

There is a question and there are two groups of people:

- 20 Men
- 80 Women

There are also 10 round tables with a capacity of 10 people. Aim is place 8 women and 2 men at each table.

There is no other restrictions and question is finding the number of different seating plans.

I think answer is:

- C(80, 8) x C(20,2) x 7! x 1!

Women groups of 8 (C(80,8) with circular seating plan (7!)

Men groups of 2 (C(20,2) with circular seating plan (1!).

However, I am not sure about my answer and also I do not integrate the possibility of 10 different tables (identical).

Can you help me about this problem?

Comment: Choosing $8$ of the $80$ women and $2$ of the $20$ men fills one table, not ten.  Also, if there are no other restrictions on the seating arrangements at each table, there are $9!$ ways to seat $10$ people at a round table.

Comment: Suppose that tables are distinguishable then number of ways to choose people for all tables is equal
$\prod_{i=1}^{10} {88-8i \choose 8} {22-2i \choose 2}=\prod_{i=1}^{10} \frac{(88-8i)!}{(80-8i)!\cdot 8!}\frac{(22-2i)!}{(20-2i)!\cdot 2!}=\frac{80!\cdot 20!}{(8!)^{10}\cdot (2!)^{10}}$
If tables are indistinguishable then one needs to divide this number by $10!$
Suppose that every position in table is distinguishable then number of ways to seat 10 people is $10!$. If only order around table is important, then number of ways to seat 10 people is $9!$.

Answer (score 1):

I am guided by the comment of N.F.Taussig.

First, I will assume that the tables are distinguishable from each other so that seating Person-1 at Table-1 is distinct from seating Person-1 at Table-2.  Then, I will adjust the answer to accommodate the alternative problem of assuming that the tables are indistinguishable from each other.

---

The number of ways of **assigning** the $80$ women, $8$ to a table to Table-1, then Table-2, ..., then Table-10, in that order is:

$$A = \binom{80}{8} \times \binom{72}{8} \times \binom{64}{8} \times \binom{56}{8} $$

$$ \times \binom{48}{8} \times \binom{40}{8} \times \binom{32}{8} $$

$$ \times \binom{24}{8} \times \binom{16}{8} \times \binom{8}{8}. $$

Therefore,

$$A = \frac{(80)!}{[8!]^{(10)}}.$$

---

The number of ways of **assigning** the $20$ men, $2$ to a table to Table-1, then Table-2, ..., then Table-10, in that order is:

$$B = \binom{20}{2} \times \binom{18}{2} \times \binom{16}{2} \times \binom{14}{2} $$

$$ \times \binom{12}{2} \times \binom{10}{2} \times \binom{8}{2} $$

$$ \times \binom{6}{2} \times \binom{4}{2} \times \binom{2}{2}. $$

Therefore,

$$B = \frac{(20)!}{[2!]^{(10)}}.$$

---

Once the assignments are made at Table-1, the $10$ people assigned to Table-1 must be seated.  Since the table is circular, rather than a straight row, and no mention has been made that the seats are labeled, you can arbitrarily designate any person to be in the *12-O'clock* position.

This means that since the table is circular, there are $(9)!$ different seating arranges for the $(10)$ people assigned to the table, rather than $(10)!$.

This analysis applies to each of the $(10)$ tables independently.

Therefore, once the people are assigned to each of the $(10)$ tables, the number of distinct seating arrangement variations is

$$C = [9!]^{(10)}.$$

So, under the assumption that the tables are **distinguishable** from each other, the final computation is

$$A \times B \times C = \frac{(80)!}{[8!]^{(10)}} \times \frac{(20)!}{[2!]^{(10)}} \times [9!]^{(10)}. \tag1 $$

---

It now remains to adjust the computation in (1) above to accommodate the alternate assumption that the tables are to be considered **indistinguishable** from each other.  The easiest approach is to consider each table as a fixed separate (**but anonymous**) entity, once the assignments and seating is set.

Then, you can pretend that instead of regarding the tables as distinguishable, you created $(10)$ labels: label-1, label-2, ..., label-10, and randomly assigned these labels to the tables.

There are $(10)!$ ways that these labels could be assigned to the tables.  These $(10)!$ labeling possibilities are inherent in the computation represented by (1) above.  That is, the computation in (1) above was based on the idea that the **order** that the tables were filled, first by women, and then by men, is pertinent.  That is, first women were assigned to Table-1.  Then to Table-2, and so on.  Ditto for the men.

Therefore, the only adjustment necessary to accommodate the alternate assumption that the tables are **indistinguishable** from each other is to multiply the computation in (1) above by the **over-counting** adjustment factor of $~\displaystyle \frac{1}{[10]!}.$  **Symbolically**, this signifies that the $(10)!$ ways of assigning labels to the tables are not to be considered pertinent.

Therefore, the final computation will be

$$\frac{A \times B \times C}{[10]!}.$$